# PowerShell implementation of xcopy

Tags: command-line, powershell

Is there a way to replicate an xcopy functional using powershell?

I thought it was an easy question until I tried some cmdlets.

Let's imagine I've got a folder structure like:

src

|-a

|-b

There're files in each folder of course. I need to copy contents of Src to some folder Dst.

With xcopy it'd be like this:

```
xcopy src dst\ /e /y
```

PS analog would be something like this:

```
copy-item src dst\ -force -recurse -verbose
```

Works great... the first time. The second time it creates a subfolder dst\src and puts files there!

I can't figure out any easy workaround. Can you?

p.s. I know I can use xcopy in PS.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```powershell
copy-item c:\\src\\* c:\\dst -force -recurse -verbose
```

Comment: the problem with the second command is that it flattens the folder structure.

Comment: copy-item c:\src\* c:\dst -force -recurse -verbose works w/o flattings!

Comment: clarification. first time it flattens the structure. the second time it creates the valid second level folders and copy files there. so it works fine when the dest folder structure is already created.

Comment: You have to create destination folder before. the best is create a function that verify if folder exist or not and act belong the case)

Comment: if (!(Test-Path -path $destDir))
    {
    New-Item $destDir -itemtype directory -force
    }

Comment: Shouldn't it be simply `copy-item src\* dst -force -recurse -verbose` ? Why c: and the double slashes?

Comment: @CB. is right, this works very well, and with variables too! Like when you want to copy your profile (just one file) to all the servers, etc., you can use $profile in PS as the source!
'copy-item c:\src* c:\dst -force -verbose'

Answer (score 1):

Here's another workaround I found here: 
 https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Cmdlets/Copy-Item/Inconsistent-destination  I've tried in the past to do this myself and would revert back to xcopy.  This is "idempotent" and will have the same result the second time.

```
mkdir $destination -Force
Copy-Item $source\* $destination -Recurse -Force
```